# Grouping/Joining The Rows Based Based on Abs Amount || Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a source table XXTB_JE_TRX like below:

| ENTITY | HEADER_ID | NET_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 10101 | -30 |
| 301 | 10101 | -50 |
| 301 | 10101 | -20 |
| 401 | 10101 | 30 |
| 402 | 10101 | 50 |
| 302 | 10101 | 20 |

and I want output (Find Related Entity) like this:

| ENTITY | HEADER_ID | NET_AMT | RELATED_ENTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 10101 | -30 | 401 |
| 301 | 10101 | -50 | 402 |
| 301 | 10101 | -20 | 302 |
| 401 | 10101 | 30 | 301 |
| 402 | 10101 | 50 | 301 |
| 302 | 10101 | 20 | 301 |

This is what I've tried:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
        entity,
        header_id,
        net_amt
    FROM
        XXTB_JE_TRX
    WHERE
        net_amt < 0
), t2 AS (
    SELECT
        entity,
        header_id,
        net_amt
    FROM
        XXTB_JE_TRX
    WHERE
        net_amt > 0
)
SELECT
    t1.entity,
    t1.header_id,
    t1.net_amt,
    t2.entity related_entity
FROM
    t1,
    t2
WHERE
        t1.header_id = t2.header_id
    AND abs(t1.net_amt) = abs(t2.net_amt)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t2.entity,
    t2.header_id,
    t2.net_amt,
    t1.entity related_entity
FROM
    t1,
    t2
WHERE
        t1.header_id = t2.header_id
    AND abs(t1.net_amt) = abs(t2.net_amt);
```

Is it a right way to do it? Can this be achieved without UNION ALL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this ought to work:

```
select a.entity_id, a.header_id, a.net_amt, b.entity_id as related_entity
  from xxtb_je_trx a join xxtb_je_trx b on a.header_id = b.header_id and a.net_amt = b.net_amt * -1;
```

You can do an `outer join` if there won't always be a related_entity. And you could do `-b.net_amt` instead of `b.net_amt * -1`.